# How to create app using yii from downloaded framework yii2

Tags: php, yii2, wamp

```
yiic webapp D:\wamp\www\test
```

sh.exe": yiic: command not found

```
yii webapp D:\wamp\www\test
```

Error: Unknown command "webapp".

Comment: You're using commands from yii1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need yiic for installing Yii2  see the getting started guide for all the information you need . You can install really easly with composer

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `init` command in `yii2`

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced>init
Yii Application Initialization Tool v1.0

Which environment do you want the application to be initialized in?

[0] Development
[1] Production

Your choice [0-1, or "q" to quit]
```